# syntax error, unexpected 'preg_replace' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, laravel

all I want to know what's the syntax error in this code.

```
echo "<p id='hide_text_$heading->id' >"preg_replace($rx, "<b>$0</b>", $heading->shortHeadline)"</p>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.` to concatenate strings. Change your code to

```
echo "<p id='hide_text_$heading->id' >" . preg_replace($rx, "<b>$0</b>", $heading->shortHeadline) . "</p>";
```

to concatenate the three parts or separate each statement:

```
echo "<p id='hide_text_$heading->id' >";
echo preg_replace($rx, "<b>$0</b>", $heading->shortHeadline);
echo "</p>";
```

More on [String Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 0):

you forget concatination sympol =>  .

**Also there is syntax error in $0 if you mean by that variable name.**

- variable name could not start with numbers
- only _ and string characters as i remember.

  ```
   echo "<p id='hide_text_".$heading->id."' >" . preg_replace($rx, "<b>.$0.</b>", $heading->shortHeadline) . "</p>";
  ```

You can read more about [Concatenation](https://www.w3schools.in/php/operators/concatenation-operators/)